# Recreating an existing edmx in Visual Studio Code for Azure Function

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, edmx

I'm trying to migrate an old API to Azure Functions. This API uses an edmx to define and connect to an Azure SQL database.

I need to recreate the code and the connection for this database in a new solution with the following conditions:

1. My newly generated edmx should match the existing database/existing code
2. When I deploy, it should NOT recreate the tables, but connect to the existing tables and interact with existing data
3. It needs to work with Azure Functions
4. I'm developing in Visual Studio Code

So far, I haven't been able to find a guide that explains how to do this. I've found a few articles on how to create an edmx from scratch, but failing conditions 2 and 4 (and not sure about 3). I'm having difficulty finding a starting point.

Is this possible, or do I need to change my approach?

Comment: can you add what you have tried and error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Porting or creating a .edmx into VS Code just isn't possible - it is no longer supported in EntityFrameworksCore. Fortunately, it isn't necessary.

First and foremost, I needed a connection to the existing database - the answer was to [Reverse Engineer the Scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) using 'Scaffold-Dbcontext,' which generated the models and the context. I needed to grab the connection string to this database from Azure for the script, but after running it I replaced the connection string with a reference to my local.settings.json so I won't be checking it into source control (See reference document, it leaves a warning in code where it does this). From there, I was able to reuse much of the original code, swapping out the new DbContext, and enabling it via dependency injection in my Startup.cs